# Como fazer um update em duas tabelas de forma alternativa que não retorne "safe update mode" no MySQL?

Tags: mysql

Eu tenho duas tabela, uma de usuários, e uma de códigos de validação.

Eu faço uma verificação do código no PHP e preciso fazer uma consulta na tabela de validação ao mesmo tempo que eu atualizo essa tabela desativando este código para que não seja validado novamente, e ative o usuário caso o código esteja correto.

Então eu estou fazendo o update deste modo:

```
UPDATE `verificaconta` as `verif`  
INNER JOIN `sysusuarios` as `usuarios` ON `usuarios`.`cod` = `verif`.`cod`
  SET `verif`.`ativo` = '0', `usuarios`.`ativo` ='1' 
  WHERE `verif`.`codvalidacao` = ?'
```

E estava me retornando o seguinte erro:

**Error Code: 1175. You are using safe update mode and you tried to update a table without a WHERE that uses a KEY column To disable safe mode, toggle the option in Preferences -> SQL Editor and reconnect.**

Pesquisei no google e aconselharam usar: `SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES = 0;`

Fiz então deste modo:

```
SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES = 0;
UPDATE `verificaconta` as `verif`  
INNER JOIN `sysusuarios` as `usuarios` ON `usuarios`.`cod` = `verif`.`cod`
  SET `verif`.`ativo` = '0', `usuarios`.`ativo` ='1' 
  WHERE `verif`.`codvalidacao` = ?'  
SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES = 1;
```

No meu servidor local, funcionou de boa, mas quando tento executar no servidor web, ele não consegue realizar a alteração.

Existe outro modo de realizar este update numa unica consulta sem que eu precise fazer um select separado do update??

---------- EDIT ----------------

**TABELA sysusuarios**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**TABELA verificaconta**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Qual é a chave primária em cada uma dessas tabelas? Você pode utilizá-las no *update*? Existe uma chave estrangeira?

Comment: @FelipeMarinho Eu atualizei a pergunta com um print das tabelas. a unica chave primaria delas é o ID. Mas neste caso eu não uso o ID nesses updates, pq não tenho como saber qual ID q vai ser modificado.

Eu nunca tive problemas em fazer update sem usar o campo do ID, esse problema ocorre por causa de uma atualização do mysql ou é pelo caso de usar um `INNER JOIN` pra comparar uma tabela com a outra? Tudo isso ainda está muito confuso pra mim.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não sei se vai servir pra você e se entendi certo o que você quer fazer, mas uma alternativa que eu gosto muito de usar é as funções do próprio MySQL.

Você pode criar uma assim pra você:

```
CREATE FUNCTION `VerificarUsuario`(codverif char(128)) RETURNS tinyint(1)
BEGIN
DECLARE codusuario varchar(20);
SELECT `cod` INTO codusuario FROM `verificaconta` WHERE `codvalidacao` = codverif;
CASE WHEN codusuario IS NOT NULL THEN
       UPDATE `sysusuarios` SET `ativo`='1' WHERE `cod`= codusuario;
       UPDATE `verificaconta` SET `ativo`='0' WHERE `cod`= codusuario;
       RETURN TRUE;
       ELSE RETURN FALSE;
END CASE;
END
```

E ai depois você chama a função com um select assim:

```
SELECT VerificarUsuario(?);
```

Acho que fica menos complicado desta forma. Assim você envia o seu código para dentro da função, e la no Mysql ele faz a verificação se o código existe, e se existir ele faz o update nas duas tabelas e retorna true (1) se não existir ele retorna false (0).

Com certeza existem dezenas de outros métodos de fazer isto, mas pra mim esse é o método que mais gosto de utilizar.

**RESOLVENDO O ERRO DO MARIA DB**

Segundo a [documentação do Maria DB](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/delimiters/), resolva da seguinte forma se der o erro: 
**ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; 
check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version
 for the right syntax to use near '' at line 3**

A solução é especificar um delimitador distinto para a duração do processo, usando o comando DELIMITER. O delimitador pode ser qualquer conjunto de caracteres que você escolher, mas precisa ser um conjunto distinto de caracteres que não cause mais confusão.

**//** é uma escolha comum e usada em toda a base de conhecimento.

Veja como a função pode ser inserida com sucesso a partir do cliente mysql com o novo delimitador.

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE FUNCTION `VerificarUsuario`(codverif char(128)) RETURNS tinyint(1)
BEGIN
DECLARE codusuario varchar(20);
SELECT `cod` INTO codusuario FROM `verificaconta` WHERE `codvalidacao` = codverif;
CASE WHEN codusuario IS NOT NULL THEN
       UPDATE `sysusuarios` SET `ativo`='1' WHERE `cod`= codusuario;
       UPDATE `verificaconta` SET `ativo`='0' WHERE `cod`= codusuario;
       RETURN TRUE;
       ELSE RETURN FALSE;
END CASE;
END

//

DELIMITER ;
```

Espero que assim resolva seu problema.

Comment: Tentei assim, mas deu erro no phpMyadmin: **ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 3**

Comment: Ahh ok, é pq o servidor que você está usando é MariaDB e não MySQL, vou atualizar a resposta de acordo com a documentação do site do Maria DB.

Comment: Funcionou, muito obrigadaaaa